# Regex match everything after conditional match

Tags: regex

am looking to match everything before (and after) zero or more from a list of items. Here is what I am currently using: `(?<=\))(.*)(?=(or|,|\())`

In this case, I want to match everything after a closing parenthesis `)` and everything before `or` `,` or `)`. This works ok (probably not optimally), however, if there are none of the 3 items match, there are no matches.

For example, the sentence `2 cups (500 ml) mushroom, or vegetable broth` matches for `mushroom,` however, `2 cups (500 ml) mushroom` doesn't match anything.

Basically, my goal is to find the ingredient from the ingredient + qty string, with the above sentence matching `mushroom` and the sentence `salt` matching the whole string `salt`

Here are more examples:

`1 thyme sprig` should match `thyme sprig`

`1 garlic clove, chopped` should match `garlic clove`

`1 cup (180 g) quinoa, rinsed and drained` should match `quinoa`

`2 tbsp (30 ml) olive oil, plus more for serving` should match `olive oil`

`Vegan Parmesan, to taste` returns `Vegan Parmesan`

The difference between the first 2 and last 2 is tricky, as if there is a closing parenthesis (as in the last 2 examples), the ingredient should be after the closing parenthesis. If there are no closing parenthesis (as in the first 2 examples, everything after the number should be taken.

Comment: Can you provide more examples and what should be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
(?:^[^)\n]*\)|\d)\s*\K.*?(?=or|[,(]|$)
```

If your regex flavor does not support `\K`, use a capturing group:

```js
(?:^[^)\n]*\)|\d)\s*(.*?)(?=or|[,(]|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C3Yi3c/5). Get Group 1 value.

*Details*:

- `(?:^[^)\n]*\)|\d)` - either start of string and then zero or more chars other than a newline or `)` char and then a `)` char, or a digit (if there is no `)` on the line)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=or|[,(]|$)` - up to the first occurrence of `or`, `,`, `(`, or end of string.

Comment: How can this be modified so that Vegan Parmesan, to taste returns Vegan Parmesan ?  So that there doesnt need to be anything prior to the ingredient ? Added an example at the end. Sorry for not adding it previously.

Comment: @VincFort I think `^(?:[^)\n]*\)|\d+)?\s*(.*?)(?=or|[,(]|$)` [will do](https://regex101.com/r/C3Yi3c/7).

Answer (score 0):

Add `|$` (end of string) to the ending group: `(?<=\))(.*?)(?=(or|,|\(|$))`

Edit: After testing [here](https://regex101.com/r/1y7DrV/1), I found you also need to make the main group non-greedy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Added a precision for the difference between the first 2 and last 2 examples. `(?<=(\)|[\d]))(.*?)(?=(or|,|\(|$))` works well for the first 2, however doesnt work for the last 2.